# Copying multiple files using DOS

Tags: dos

I have different folders eg: a,b,c etc and each folder has different files eg: x,y,z etc.
The files x,y,z is in each folder. Is there a way to copy each file from different folders using a single command? I want the result to be x file from all the folders to be in one folder.

Eg:xcopy/S x*.* C:\Folder

which can copy all the x file from different folders. How can I copy x,y,z from different folders using a single command?. Thanks

Comment: Hmmm... How do you expect to put multiple files with the same name into one destination folder? That simply cannot be done. The files will have to be either renamed or merged if you want them to coexist in one folder.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use 'for' either in a batch file or directly from the cmd.

```
for %I in (file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt) do xcopy\s %I c:\somedir\
```

Instead of file name you could give the absolute/relative path for different files in different folder

Comment: Alternatively if using DOS for loop: `for %%i in ( file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt ) do ( xcopy /s %%i ..\somedir )`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with a single command in DOS.  What you need is a script like the one below.  This can be executed in the root folder of the tree you are trying to collect from, like this:

```
batch.bat x*.*
```

It will harvest all the files matching x*.* in the current directory and all subdirectories, recursively.  They will be saved in this format:

```
folder1\x1.txt - > folder1x1.txt
folder2\x5.txt - > folder2x5.txt
folder3\x1.txt - > folder3x1.txt
```

Here is the code:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR .\%1 /B /AA /S') DO (CALL :COPYFILE %%I)
GOTO END

:COPYFILE
set "ofn=%~1"
set "fn=%~1"
call:MakeRelative fn
set fn=%fn:\=%
set fn=%fn::=%
copy %ofn% %fn%
goto:eof

:MakeRelative file base -- makes a file name relative to a base path
::                      -- file [in,out] - variable with file name to be converted, or file name itself for result in stdout
::                      -- base [in,opt] - base path, leave blank for current directory
:$created 20060101 :$changed 20080219 :$categories Path
:$source http://www.dostips.com
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set src=%~1
if defined %1 set src=!%~1!
set bas=%~2
if not defined bas set bas=%cd%
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ("%src%") do set src=%%~fa
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ("%bas%") do set bas=%%~fa
set mat=&rem variable to store matching part of the name
set upp=&rem variable to reference a parent
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('echo.%bas:\=^&echo.%') do (
    set sub=!sub!%%a\
    call set tmp=%%src:!sub!=%%
    if "!tmp!" NEQ "!src!" (set mat=!sub!)ELSE (set upp=!upp!..\)
)
set src=%upp%!src:%mat%=!
( ENDLOCAL & REM RETURN VALUES
    IF defined %1 (SET %~1=%src%) ELSE ECHO.%src%
)
EXIT /b

:END
```

Hope this helps!